# 2D image coordinate to 3D world coordinate using Depth Map

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Having the intrinsic and extrinsic matrices how does one transfer 2D image coordinate to 3D world coordinate using the depth map image? A similar problem was discussed here: [2D Coordinate to 3D world coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909696/2d-coordinate-to-3d-world-coordinate), but it assumes images are rectified which is not the case here. I have a problem formulating the equation for this.

```
p_camera.x      = (pixCoord.x - cx) / fx;
p_camera.y      = (pixCoord.y - cy) / fy;
p_camera.z      = depth;

p_camera.x      = -p_camera.x*p_camera.z;
p_camera.y      = -p_camera.y*p_camera.z;

P_world = R * (p_camera + T);
```

Comment: where's your "minus" coming from in "= -p_camera.x*p_camera.z;" and same for .y? And I think it should be P_world = (R * p_camera) + T;

Comment: @Micka well the coordinates are flipped